# Facebook permission for friend's profile information

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook as signup option for my android app. I need to know what permission should i ask to get access to user's friends profile info, work history and education history, relationship status. I am using user_friends to get it but its not working. I am using this another app that uses Facebook signup and when i look at App Settings in my facebook account then following are the permissions. 
Your basic info.
Your email address (******).
Your groups.
Your location.
**Friends' profile info: birthdays, education histories, groups, interests, locations, relationship statuses, websites and work histories**(I want this permission for my app).

Please help me guys :)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your app after 4/30/2014, you're using Graph API 2.0, and all friend_* permissions have been removed.

The only way to get a friend's info is if that friend also uses your app, in which case you can ask them for permissions directly and get the info you need.

Comment: I created my app in Jan 2014. Are you saying if the user have given permission after 4/30/2014 then i can not access their friend's info? If you try to use app.connect.com, they still can take the friends info.

Comment: If you created your app in Jan 2014 then you can still request friend_* permissions. However, I would encourage you to re-think why you need those permissions because you'll have to migrate your app by 4/30/2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your app before 4/30/2014 then you can use the following permissions.

```
"friends_interests","friends_birthday","friends_about_me","friends_education_history","friends_work_history"
```